Deep Linking In React Native Widgets
Hi I am working on Widgets with a React Native Application.
From My Widgets I have to navigate to one of my screens in React-Native App. I am writing my IOS code down below
    Link(destination: URL(string: "com.app.me://viewAppComponent")!)  {
            Rectangle()
              .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.init(red: 234.0 / 255.0, green: 67.0 / 255.0, blue: 159.0 / 255.0), .init(red: 101.0 / 255.0, green: 49.0 / 255.0, blue: 207.0 / 255.0)]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)).cornerRadius(50)
              .frame(width: 139, height: 35).overlay(
                HStack(spacing: 5) {  // Add spacing between Text and Image
                  Image("comment-icon")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 17, height: 17)
                  
                  Text("Comments")
                    .font(Font.custom("Poppins", size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Constants.Color).padding(.horizontal, 10)
                  
                }
              )

And I am recieving this link in the component, right here
    useEffect(() => {
    const handleDeepLink = (event) => {
      const url = event.url;
      if (url) {
        const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
        const routeName = route.split("/")[0];
        if (routeName === "viewAppComponent") {
          navigation.navigate("stackProducts", {
            userInfo: user,
            productInfos: product,
          });
        }
      }
    };

    const getInitialURL = async () => {
      const initialURL = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      if (initialURL) {
        handleDeepLink({ url: initialURL });
      }
    };

    getInitialURL();

    const linkingListener = Linking.addEventListener("url", handleDeepLink);

    return () => {
      linkingListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

This code works perfectly, when app is running in the background, but it overrides other paths if app is in killed state.
I mean, if I try to open some screens like Home-Screen, it will again navigate to this stackProducts Screen.
Please write down the solution, or any link for me to figure out the reason
